# Malloc 2D pyramid array in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I'm having trouble creating a 2D array where every "row" would be different size array, with (2*row)+1 integers starting with row=0.

The thing that troubles me it that the code work for some small inputs (1,2,3) but then crashes on 4 if I try to free the structure after printing or on 5 if I don't free the memory.

```
typedef struct{
    int nrow;
    int** numbers;
} pyramid;

pyramid* create_pyramid(int nrow){
    //Allocate memory for pyramid
    pyramid *p = (pyramid *) malloc (sizeof(pyramid));
    if(p == NULL) exit(1);

    p->nrow = nrow;

    //Allocate memory for numbers
    p->numbers = (int**) malloc (sizeof(int*));
    if(p->numbers == NULL) exit(1);

    //Alocate memory for numbers[i]
    int i, nums;
    for(i = 0; i < nrow; i++){
        nums = (i*2) + 1;

        p->numbers[i] = (int*) malloc (nums * sizeof(int));
        if(p->numbers[i] == NULL) exit(1);
    }

    return p;
}

void print_pyramid(pyramid *p){
    int i, j, nums, spaces;
    for(i = 0; i < p->nrow; i++){
        nums = (2*i)+1;
        spaces = p->nrow - (i+1);
        for(j = 0; j < spaces; j++) printf(" ");
        for(j = 0; j < nums; j++){
            printf("%d",p->numbers[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void free_pyramid(pyramid *p){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < p->nrow; i++){
        free(p->numbers[i]);
    }
    free(p->numbers);
    free(p);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc<2) exit(1);

    int nrow; sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &nrow);
    pyramid *p = create_pyramid(nrow);
    print_pyramid(p);
    free_pyramid(p);
    exit(0);
}
```

This is what I get when running this code with command line arguments 0-4:

```
userT@userT-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pyr$ ./a.out 1
0
userT@userT-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pyr$ ./a.out 2
 0
000
userT@userT-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pyr$ ./a.out 3
  0
 000
00000
userT@userT-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pyr$ ./a.out 4
   0
  000
 00000
0000000
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001441050 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fcc5a32d7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7fcc5a335e0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fcc5a33998c]
./a.out[0x400887]
./a.out[0x40092a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fcc5a2d6830]
./a.out[0x4005e9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 38534                              /home/userT/Desktop/pyr/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 38534                              /home/userT/Desktop/pyr/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 38534                              /home/userT/Desktop/pyr/a.out
01441000-01462000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fcc54000000-7fcc54021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc54021000-7fcc58000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc5a0a0000-7fcc5a0b6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7136                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcc5a0b6000-7fcc5a2b5000 ---p 00016000 08:01 7136                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcc5a2b5000-7fcc5a2b6000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 7136                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcc5a2b6000-7fcc5a475000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7098                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fcc5a475000-7fcc5a675000 ---p 001bf000 08:01 7098                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fcc5a675000-7fcc5a679000 r--p 001bf000 08:01 7098                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fcc5a679000-7fcc5a67b000 rw-p 001c3000 08:01 7098                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fcc5a67b000-7fcc5a67f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc5a67f000-7fcc5a6a5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7070                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fcc5a887000-7fcc5a88a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc5a8a1000-7fcc5a8a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc5a8a4000-7fcc5a8a5000 r--p 00025000 08:01 7070                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fcc5a8a5000-7fcc5a8a6000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 7070                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fcc5a8a6000-7fcc5a8a7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffc634cc000-7ffc634ed000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc635d6000-7ffc635d8000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc635d8000-7ffc635da000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And this if what I get if I don't call the free_pyramid function at the end of main:

```
userT@userT-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pyr$ ./a.out
userT@userT-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pyr$ ./a.out 1
0
userT@userT-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pyr$ ./a.out 2
 0
000
userT@userT-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pyr$ ./a.out 3
  0
 000
00000
userT@userT-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pyr$ ./a.out 4
   0
  000
 00000
0000000
userT@userT-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pyr$ ./a.out 5
    39268576
   000
  00000
 0000000
000000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was debugging this for 2 hours and just couldn't figure out what was wrong.

Corrected line:
   `p->numbers = (int **) malloc (nrow * sizeof(int *));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you do in

```
p->numbers[i] = (int*) malloc (nums * sizeof(int));
```

you need to allocate memory for an array of variables, not only one variable. So this line:

```
p->numbers = (int**) malloc (sizeof(int*));
```

should be

```
p->numbers = (int**) malloc (nrow * sizeof(int*));
```

In both cases `(int*)` and `(int**)` are not needed.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanics of how to allocate memory properly have already been addressed, but regarding your question:

*The thing that troubles me it that* ***the code work for some small inputs (1,2,3) but then crashes on 4*** *if I try to free the structure after printing or on 5 if I don't free the memory.*

Even if you do not yet own it, your program can appear to work fine when attempting to write to a location in memory that has not been properly allocated. This is referred to as *[undefined behavior (a)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/undefined-behavior-c-cpp/)*. Your program appears to work fine, then all of the sudden, for no apparent reason, it does not.

Later, regarding freeing memory, The `free` statement only *marks memory locations* to allow the operating system to use when it needs them.  It does not immediately clear the contents of that memory. So, if you attempt to access that same memory location after freeing, and it has not yet been used by the operating system for something else, you may actually appear to have success at seeing content.  This again is *[undefined behavior (b)](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)*.

Again, the real question of how to allocate memory has been addressed, but because there is a nice, consistent numeric ratio of columns to rows in your pyramid design, your create_pyramid function can be simplified.  (This example does not use the struct, and populates each row `n` with the with the number `n`.)

```
int ** create_pyramid(int r);

int main(void)
{
    int r = 5;
    int **p = Create2D(r);
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<(2*i)+1;j++)
        {
            p[i][j] = i; //populate with numeral representing row.
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int ** create_pyramid(int r)
{   
    int **arr;
    int c = 2*r-1;
    int    y = 0;

    arr   = calloc(c, sizeof(int *));
    for(y=0;y<c;y++)
    {
        arr[y] = calloc((2*y)+1, sizeof(int));  
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Illustration of memory created: (showing only first few *rows* to conserve space)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
p->numbers = (int**) malloc (sizeof(int*));
```

should be

```
p->numbers = malloc ( sizeof(int*[nrow]) );
```

The cast to `int**` is superfluous, and you need to allocate an array of pointers rather than one single pointer.

Comment: Unclear what `sizeof(int*[nrow])` is.  Suggest `p->numbers = malloc (sizeof p->numbers[0] * nrow);`

Comment: @chux `int*` is a pointer to an integer. `int* [n]` is the type used for an array of `n` pointers to integers. `sizeof()` with parenthesis gives the size of the type - here evaluated in run-time since the array type passed is a VLA.

Comment: Interesting, forming the size of a VLA to construct the size to allocate to `p->numbers`.  This approach would be more applicable had `p->numbers` been a pointer to a VLA.

Comment: @chux The most formally correct type to use for `p->numbers` would actually have been a `int(*)[n]`, since it is a pointer to an array. But instead the OP points to the first element of an array, which is OK too and probably easier to use in practice.